# How can I fix this error "RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN."?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, error-handling

I recently downloaded Windows 11 on my system and ever since (I do not know if that is the main issue) I start my react.js app with "npm start" and activate nodemon in my terminal, I get a "**RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN**" error.

The app itself is available at my localhost:3000, but in one section of my app, I have the following code that fetches data from my node express server (by using app.get()) that connects with a Postgres database.

**recipe-cards.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const RecipeSection = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
 
    useEffect(() => {
        let interval;
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const url = "http://localhost:8000/recipes/display";
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const json = await response.json();

                setData(json);
                
            } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
    };

    fetchData();

    interval = setInterval(() => {
        fetchData()
      }, 86 * 1000)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }

    }, []); // Determine swhen to re-use useEffect, if this changes.

    return (
        <section className='recipe-card-grid'>
            {data.map(recipe => 
                (
                    <article key={recipe.recipe_id} className='recipe-card'>
                
                        <a href={recipe.video_url} rel='noopener noreferrer nofollow' target='_blank'>
                            <img src={recipe.img_path} alt={recipe.alt} className='recipe-card-image' />
                            <h2 className='center-text'>{recipe.recipe}</h2>
                        </a>
                        
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <img className='recipe-card-clock-icon' 
                                        src='/assets/ux/recipe-card-icons/clock.png' 
                                        alt='An icon that informs you about how long it might take to cook this recipe' />
                                    </td>
                                    <th>
                                        <p>&#8776;{recipe.cooking_time} min</p>
                                    </th> 
                                    <td>
                                        <img className='recipe-card-servings-icon' 
                                        src='/assets/ux/recipe-card-icons/servings.png' 
                                        alt='An icon that informs you about how many people can be served by following this recipe' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>
                                        <p>x{recipe.servings} servings</p>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                            
                        <p className='center-text'>{recipe.summary}</p>

                    </article> 

                )
            )}
        </section>
    )
};

//RecipeSection
export default RecipeSection;
```

**The code corresponding to the route that I am trying to access to get the database data.**

```
const pool = require('../../database/poolConfig.js');

const displayRecipes = (req, res) => {
    
    const recipeFilter = 'SELECT * FROM recipes ORDER BY recipe_id ASC';
  
    pool.query(recipeFilter, (error, results) => {
      
      if(error) {
        console.error(error);

        res.status(403).json({
            success : false,
            msg : 'Could not display recipes.'
        })
      }

      const recipeJSON = results.rows; //!! results.rows[0]["recipe"]

      res.status(200).send(
          recipeJSON
        );
    })
}
```

Normally this code would populate my website with links and images corresponding to cooking recipes that I have prepared in my Postgres database, but now it does not do anything, except show the following error.

**Nodemon error in terminal**

```
RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received NaN.
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at validatePort (node:internal/validators:216:11)
    at lookupAndConnect (node:net:1013:5)
    at Socket.connect (node:net:989:5)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:38:17)
    at Client._connect (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:113:11)
    at Client.connect (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:161:12)
    at BoundPool.newClient (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:229:12)
    at BoundPool.connect (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:204:10)
    at BoundPool.query (C:\Users\hardg\Desktop\dj-bbq\node_modules\pg-pool\index.js:361:10)
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Does anyone have some ideas or should I provide more info?

**package.json content**

```
{
  "name": "not-set",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "--",
  "author": "not-set",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "11.x"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@formspree/react": "^2.2.4",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.5.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.19.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "pg": "^8.7.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "stripe": "^8.184.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node app-server/server.js",
    "nodemon": "nodemon app-server/server.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I made a regular app.get() route...

```
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('The Basic API endpoints are working.')
    });
```

...and I tested it with Postman after writing npm start in one terminal and started nodemon. The result was that Postman was able to reach the API endpoint and return 'The Basic API endpoints are working.'

What that means is that the Port is being set and that API endpoints can be accessed. Thus the issue has to be with the recipe-cards.js file (probably). Either the "node-Postgres" aka "pg" dependency is causing the issue or something else. I will keep testing and debugging.

Comment: Seems an issue in the express server setup that is not receiving "8000" as a listen port. Can you show your express server code lauching and how it sets the port 8000?

Comment: Please show the code from poolConfig.js

Comment: What does *database/poolConfig.js* do? Please show us the relevant setup for node-postgres

Comment: @LuizFernandodaSilva This is my server.js file that sets-up the express backend - https://codeshare.io/Qnk0Ex .

Comment: @RobertKawecki This is what is located in poolConfig.js - https://codeshare.io/K8Z0x8 . It sets the data that I need to use with pool.query() ( from "pg" dependency ) to connect with my Postgres database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix it. The issue was with my .env file and 'dotenv' dependency. In short, the error was not talking about the express server 'port' but about the Postgres database 'port' that the 'pg' dependency wanted to use to access the database I have set up on my own local machine by using 'pool.query()' and info that I had set up at the .env files that corresponded with the database: user, database_name, port, password, etc.
One of the environmental variables, in my case, the 'port' had changed so I had to change in in the .env file to the new one.
I hope that makes sense.